# UWP Flyout loopingselector

Tags: windows-10, uwp, flyout, loopingselector

I am currently building a new Windows 10 UWP app based on our previous Windows Phone 7 app. In this old app we have a specific control where the user needs to select a value between 1 and 101, for this we used the loopingselector.

Now for the UWP app it seems that this control is not available anymore. What I'm looking for is similar to the timepicker flyout but then with only one selector from 1-101.

I have searched quite a bit but maybe I'm missing something. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: The only one I've seen for WinRT is this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/04/16/winrt-create-a-custom-itemspanel-for-an-itemscontrol.aspx it has an example on how to create a LoopItemsPanel - what looks like the old loopingSelector. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) If we can't use a native control this is definitely an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.aspx) control. With a little of [Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.aspx) tweaking you can create similar look to LoopingSelector.

Comment: can you share code snippet for the styling? it will be helpful.